# Refreshing a part of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know if this is possible but I'd like to refresh the contents in a div when a button is clicked.

Example:

```
 <div id="div"> 
 Some contents
</div>
<input type="button" value="button" onClick="div.refresh()"/>
```

I'm not trying to change the contents of the div just to refresh only that part of the page.

Is this possible?

Comment: What ideas have you already considered? What have you tried? Please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) about writing a good question for SO. What you want to do is certainly possible, but some more context will help people point you in the right direction.

Comment: I've tried location.refresh() and it worked but it refreshes the whole page. i was just wondering if i can refresh only that div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following example, the jQuery [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function returns the content of the site `page.html`, searches the DOM element (here with id `div2`) and remembers the HTML content. The HTML content of the main selected DOM element (here with id `div1`) is replaced with the new content.

```
$('#div1').load('page.html #div2');
```

The following code will replace your `div` html with the current content.

```
function div_refresh() {
    $('#div').load(window.location.href + ' #div');
}
```

Also see my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/qkUe7/show/).

Answer (score 0):

> Im not trying to change the contents of the div just to refresh only
>   that part of the page.

That doesn't make much sense.  If you want to refresh part of the page, you want to change content somewhere...

Anyway, it's certainly possible.

if your div has attribute `id="myDiv"` then you would do something like

`$('#myDiv').html('updated content');`

as a simple example.  The `$('#myDiv')` has jquery select the element with id `myDiv`, and the `html`  call changes to value in the div...Documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Again, that's a really simple example of how to change the content of just a div with jQuery....